# mean in RCPP slower than R mean

Tags: performance, rcpp

Interested in Rcpp, I copied a simple example from Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R":

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total / n;
}

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
x <- runif(1e5)
microbenchmark(
  mean(x),
  meanC(x)
)
*/
```

which gives me:

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
  mean(x) 149.412 161.4115 181.1470 180.3395 204.2910  216.656   100  a 
 meanC(x) 394.605 400.4335 489.2311 481.6755 539.6835 1425.628   100   b
```

It seems that meanC() is substantially slower than mean()! Why?
Can I do anything to speed up meanC?

Tested on macOS Catalina 64bit.

Comment: For me `meanC` is about twice as fast than `mean`. What compiler options do you use? `Rcpp::sourceCpp(..., verbose = TRUE)` will show you which options are used.

Comment: There is a sugar mean. Can you try  i++ instead of ++i

Comment: Like Ralf, I get `meanC()` to be faster than `mean()` -- about 88usec to 133usec for the median.  Ubuntu 19.10, g++-9.2.

Comment: Here is what ```sourceCpp('meanC.cpp',verbose=T, rebuild=T)```
tells me:
```

Comment: The output is probably to long for a comment. Better [edit] the question to include the additional information.

Comment: Here is what ```sourceCpp('meanC.cpp',verbose=T, rebuild=T)```
tells me:
```/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_3.so' --preclean  'meanC.cpp'  
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/ruf/FilesR/PROG" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -c meanC.cpp -o meanC.o ```

Comment: @MACHERKIME I get the same times using i++

Comment: Please use sugar::mean for test. Then, It  a problem  with compilar parameters

Comment: For me the Sugar variant scores about the same as the R variant. For this simple example the function call overhead matter.  I suspect OP's problem is the lack of optimization switches in the compiler call -- no idea why.  On Linux we generally get `-O3` from the OS / the R setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the code in the main loop for a (manual) `mean()` is so simple, *optmization settings matter greatly*.

If I enforce `-O0` (and note that `-g` is also used):

```
R> microbenchmark(mean(x), meanC(x), meanS(x)
+ )
Unit: microseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval cld
  mean(x)  653.089  654.093  693.971  670.952  708.419 1090.22   100 a  
 meanC(x) 1922.536 1951.835 2067.521 1980.786 2058.981 3078.64   100  b 
 meanS(x) 3409.202 3467.219 3660.131 3520.522 3618.264 5999.65   100   c
R>
```

If I use -O1, or the -O3 default value I commonly use I get essentially identical results. Here is `-O3`:

```
R> microbenchmark(mean(x), meanC(x), meanS(x)
+ )
Unit: microseconds
     expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq      max neval cld
  mean(x) 653.006 653.400 683.852 668.616 699.988  869.978   100   b
 meanC(x) 435.107 435.435 460.909 438.860 465.111 1078.962   100  a 
 meanS(x) 652.505 652.873 689.620 660.695 693.213 1270.513   100   b
R>
```

If I try `-O6 -march=native` I get about he same. There is not too much one can do, and the compiler apparently is good enough to add something worthwhile even at easiest settings.

Code below

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanC(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double total = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    total += x[i];
  }
  return total / n;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double meanS(const Rcpp::NumericVector& x) {
  return Rcpp::mean(x);
}

/*** R
library(microbenchmark)
x <- runif(5e5)
microbenchmark(mean(x), meanC(x), meanS(x)
)
*/
```

Comment: Adding -O3 did it for me. Now meanC() is appr. 50% faster than mean(). Thanks!